# how to add multiple parameters in data set for BIRT report

Tags: birt

how to add multiple parameters in data set for BIRT report ,till now i am able to add only one parameter.
my sql query for datset is

```
select cid,attdate,intime,outtime
```

from att_emp_swipe 
where attdate >= ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use multiple `?`-s.

```
select cid,attdate,intime,outtime
from att_emp_swipe where attdate >= ? 
and something_else = ?
```

Data set parameters are bound in order of `?` apperance.